# Are there autofocus-enabled adapters for Olympus lenses on Canon EOS cameras?

Tags: canon, autofocus, lens-adapter, olympus

[image]Fairly new to photography so forgive my foolishness before calling me out, I already know.

I bought a Olympus 50mm F1.8 lens thinking it was a manual focus but when I received it I realized I misread and actually bought an autofocus.

I currently have a Canon EOS Rebel T6 so the autofocus feature of course isn't working, but is there any possible way to buy an adapter that would allow for the autofocus feature to work or am I better off just reselling the lens to someone who could actually use it?

Comment: Actually now that I check its not an OM, its just an Olympus Lens AF 50mm 1:1,8. I guess it must have been listed improperly online since the listing said "Olympus OM AF 50mm f/1.8 Autofocus Camera Lens". But there is no manual focus ring on the lens

Comment: That indeed seems to be an OM lens (judging from [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Olympus-50mm-F1-8-Camera-OM-77AF/dp/B000QVZVO8) results of the exact same lens here). All I'm able to find is EF(-S) to OM with AF, but not the other way around.

Comment: Bummer, luckily it was only a $17 purchase so I could be way worse off. Thanks for all your help anyway :)

Comment: Andrew, don't waste money buying random lenses. Have a read through [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: @osullic In this case, the issue wasn't so much randomness as that the OP misread the listing. The (far more common) manual focus "Auto-S" OM lenses adapt very nicely to EF mount. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [flange-focal distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) only differs by a couple of mm between OM and EF mount, which means that the adapters are thin wafers of metal, with no space for adding electronics. It might be *possible*, but the extreme difficulty, combined with the fact that [the auto-focus OMs weren't very popular](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Olympus_OM-707_/_OM-77) compared to the manual models, means that there isn't much incentive for anyone to put the work into trying to produce such an adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't even a widely available commercial adapter to use OM AF/PF lenses *manually*. These rare lenses (which only fit two and a half mediocre-featured film camera models) have a mechanical aperture control but no aperture ring on the lens, and they are so obscure that no one yet marketed even a NEX bayonet adapter (which you can readily buy for lenses as obscure as Pentax 110 or 1960's Kodak bayonet) with the aperture slider you would need for OM AF.

These won't even fit on all OM adapters due to extra coupling elements.

Some of these can be manually focused by simply pulling and pushing on the front part, there will still be no aperture control (which would be nigh impossible to implement in a glassless adapter for EOS - there needs to be a motor in the adapter!) unless you are willing to hack the lens and unmount it to change aperture.